# how to change a list of n integers in python to normal space separated integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

so I had a ques that wanted me to reverse the entered array by the user and print it as output.
now I did it in python  but I got an output,
 similar to this: **[2, 3, 4, 1]**
but I need the output in this format: **2 3 4 1**
how should I do it?

P.S: this is a ques on hackerrank .
Q.Given an array, A, of N integers, print A's elements in reverse order as a single line of space-separated numbers.
**Input Format**
The first line contains an integer, N (the size of our array).
The second line contains space-separated integers describing array A's elements.

**Output Format**

Print the elements of array A in reverse order as a single line of space-separated numbers.

Sample Input

4
1 4 3 2
Sample Output

2 3 4 1

```
n = int(input())

arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
new_arr=arr[::-1]
print(new_arr)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `print(' '.join(new_arr))` ?

Comment: n = int(input())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    new_arr=arr[::-1]
    print=(' '.join(new_arr))
but it has a different error message this time.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 16, in <module>
    print=int(' '.join(new_arr))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Oh my bad... `print(' '.join(map(str, new_arr)))` should be better

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) parameter of print here.

```
print(*new_arr,sep=' ')
# 2 3 4 1
```

*print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)*

> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end, file and flush, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.

**Note:** The default value of `sep` is `' '`, so `print(*new_arr)` will work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion that worked. but is there any other way to do so also how can we do this  in c++?